# Running Artisan from ssh on web host not working

Tags: laravel-4

I uploaded a local copy of Laravel into my webhosting service (justhost). Now im trying to use artisan but it doesnt give any output. It just gives me `Content-type: text/html`


**For example**

```
username@website.com [~/www]# php artisan --version
Content-type: text/html
```

Any Idea whats going on?

Comment: you have to be in the laravel folder in order to use the artisan command. Or if your www is sering as the public folder of laravel you should move the artisan file in it i think

Comment: @DimitrisKontoulis artisan is located at `www`

Comment: have you tried any other commands? like the single php artisan  which will give you the command list

Comment: @DimitrisKontoulis yes i did, nothing, same thing

Answer (score 0):

Justhost hast not support to php 5.3^ from terminal access in shared host, you need to run specific php version to run artisan, something like `/bin/php56 artinsan --version`.

is the same case to run composer on JustHost shared host.